# Weighted Sum of Digits

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the weighted sum of digits for example if I have 124 I need to make it: 1 * 1 + 2 * 2 + 4 * 3.

So far I have been able to multiply the numbers using a for loop like so:

```
Console.WriteLine("Input a number");
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int digit = 0;

for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--)
{                
    digit = num % 10 * i;
    num /= 10;
    Console.WriteLine(digit);
}
```

But I'm unsure as to how to add the numbers after.

Comment: What did you try? What problems did you encounter. Do you know how to add up two numbers? Do you know how to add up all numbers in your loop?

Comment: I tried 1776 for the number. I got the multiplication of the numbers down. I just don't know how to add up all of the numbers after. I'm unsure on what to try next. I do know how to add 2 numbers. Just not the numbers after the loop is finished

Comment: Well that's because you cannot. When the loop is finished, the numbers are gone. You need to add them add while the loop is running.

Comment: Ok how do I do that? Like I get all of my numbers multiplied but I still have to add them up. That's where I'm stuck

Comment: Someone posted the answer then deleted it but it worked. How do I mark as answered? I'm new to this

Comment: I'm sure this was taught before. The solution should be in your textbook or notes. Start with creating a variable for it and then add the digits one by one as you calculate them.

Comment: @nvoigt I'm actually not learning this in any classes. This is a project I found online that I was trying to do on my own

Comment: @nvoigt, I agreed to your words and deleted the answer; I appreciate if OP solve this issue by his own

Comment: Well, no matter how you got to the question you have, Stack Overflow is not built to *teach* you. You need a good textbook or teacher for that. Please get one and do the exercises.

Comment: @nvoigt I disagree. This is a place where you go when you can't figure something out and you ask for help. I have seen 100's of questions like this on this sight that people were happy to help with. Also it says when you sign up that this is a place to learn and share knowledge. Which is what teaching is

Comment: Not like this as in this question but on similar levels

Comment: No you misunderstand something. People learn from things. I can learn from a car crash. I can learn from a ready-made solution posted here. But neither the car crash nor the solution here is *teaching*. Teaching requires structure. We cannot provide that structure here, the site is not made for that. What you need is a teacher (be it a book, youtube channel or person) that structures your learning, not piecemeal solutions without explanations like the answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this for 4 digits numbers

```
Console.WriteLine("Input a number");
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--)
{                
    sum += num % 10 * i;
    num /= 10;
}

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

but if you want your code work for any number, do this

```
Console.WriteLine("Input a number");
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int sum = 0;

for (int i = num.ToString().Length; i > 0; i--)
{                
    sum += num % 10 * i;
    num /= 10;
}

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Comment: Please don't feed people basic trivia like that. You are doing their homework for them. They copy your answer instead of doing their own work and learning about programming in the process. The OP does not need Stack Overflow, they need to flip back a page in their textbook and do what everybody else does. Study.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to achieve this?

```
Console.WriteLine("Input a number");
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int digit = 0;
int i=num.ToString().Length;
int Sum= 0;
int digit2=0;
while(num>0)
{
digit= num%10;
digit2=digit*i;
Sum=Sum+digit2;
num=num/10;
i--;
}
Console.Writeline(Sum);
```

Comment: in example, 4 must be multiplied in 3 not 1

Comment: I understand the question wrong,i  have updated my code now.

Comment: Please don't feed people basic trivia like that. You are doing their homework for them. They copy your answer instead of doing their own work and learning about programming in the process. The OP does not need Stack Overflow, they need to flip back a page in their textbook and do what everybody else does. Study.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int num, sum = 0, r;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number : ");
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());          
       var add_n=(num.ToString().Length)+1;
        while (num != 0)
        {

            r = num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
            //Console.WriteLine(r+" "+(add_n-1));
            sum = sum + (r*(add_n-1));
            add_n--;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of Digits of the Number : "+sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What does this offer over the other answers from half an hour ago?

Answer (score 0):

If you are for simple solution (which is not very fast) you can try *Linq*:

```
Console.WriteLine("Input a number");
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" + ", num
  .Select((c, i) => $"{c - '0'} * {i + 1}")););
```

Outcome:

```
1 * 1 + 2 * 2 + 4 * 3
```

If you want to find out the sum, add `Sum`:

```
int sum = num
  .Select((c, i) => (c - '0') * (i + 1))
  .Sum();
```